# Spark: persist and repartition order

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partition, persist

I have the following code:

```
val data = input.map{... }.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER).repartition(2000)
```

I am wondering what's the difference if I do the repartition first like:

```
val data = input.map{... }.repartition(2000).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Is there a difference in the order of calling reparation and persist? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

In the first case you get persist RDD after map phase. It means that every time `data` is accessed it will trigger `repartition`.

In the second case you cache after repartitioning. When `data` is accessed, and has been previously materialized, there is no additional work to do.

To prove lets make an experiment:

```scala
import  org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

val data1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 8)
  .map(identity)
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
  .repartition(2000)
data1.count()

val data2 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 8)
  .map(identity)
  .repartition(2000)
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
data2.count()
```

and take a look at the storage info:

```scala
sc.getRDDStorageInfo

// Array[org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo] = Array(
//   RDD "MapPartitionsRDD" (17) StorageLevel:
//       StorageLevel(false, true, false, false, 1);
//     CachedPartitions: 2000; TotalPartitions: 2000; MemorySize: 8.6 KB; 
//     ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B,
//   RDD "MapPartitionsRDD" (7) StorageLevel:
//      StorageLevel(false, true, false, false, 1);
//    CachedPartitions: 8; TotalPartitions: 8; MemorySize: 668.0 B; 
//    ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B)
```

As you can see there are two persisted RDDs, one with 2000 partitions, and one with 8.

Comment: I'm two years late to comment. but data1.getNumPartitions and data2.getNumPartitions both returns 2000

Comment: @hadooper It should. The intermediate objects are differ, not the final ones.

Comment: Could you please explain more on intermediate objects?

Comment: @hadooper the point is in one scenario Spark save the RDD in 8 partitions and in the other scenario first do a shuffle and after it saves the RDD in 2000 partitions. If you need 2000 partitions after the second approach is better because the shuffle is executed once (before persist).

Comment: @hadooper number of partitions persisted(8 vs 2000)